# $\lim_{x \to0} (\sin(2x)-2x)/x^3$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Evaluate $$
> \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(2x)-2x}{x^3}
> $$

I thought that I could use L'Hopital's rule to get to an answer of $-1$ but according to the answer manual that isn't correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the steps you took to get $-1$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! How did you get an answer of $-1$? Please add your work to your question with an [edit]. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You can use L'Hopital's rule (thrice)  to get to an answer of $-4/3$. You can also use other techniques to get the same answer. Unclear how you use L'Hopital to get $-1$, however: detailing it would help us help you find your mistake.

Comment: If you show us how you got your answer, we could presumably find any error in it. But if you don't show us, then how can we know where any mistakes are?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is the solution, you keep using L Hospital's Rule until you get the denominator as a number or an integer instead of x, since x-> 0 means the denominator will be 0 which wont solve our problem.

Kindly message me if you have problems or concerns in understanding this.

Answer (score 2):

A better method would be using Taylor series:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(2x)-2x}{x^3} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x-\frac{(2x)^3}{3!}+O(x^5)-2x}{x^3} = -\frac{4}{3},
$$
where we used $\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$.